# How does Titan stores data in HBASE

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, titan, tinkerpop

I would like to know how graphs are stored when Titan DB uses HBASE as its data storage.

Why I am asking: assume that I want to leverage BOTH the Titan interface (ie interact with my data as a graph) and also be able, from time to time, to execute queries (say via Hive) 
by-passing Titan (the rationale for this could be situations in which I need more SQL-ish types of queries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page describes how Titan stores data in the various backends:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Titan-Data-Model

The data that Titan stores within this model is encoded and compressed for optimal efficiency when reading and writing data.  As a result, trying to access it with external tools will not work so well.  For queries over the entire graph (which is what I think you are referring to with this question) use [Faunus](http://faunus.thinkaurelius.com) to either:

1. directly query the graph to get your answer
2. or use it to extract the data from Titan, transforming it to a format that might then be consumable by other tools.

Comment: Yes, looks like trying to access the data in HBase via some other tool, say Hive, is hopeless (perhaps I will look into the other persistence back end for Titan, namely Cassandra). Actually, what I had in mind is not that; my use case is: suppose you need to store the data so that SQL folks can query it their way, but u like it the graph way (Faunus gives u the capability of doing global graph queries, but ain't no substitute for SQL). Unfortunately, it was just wishful thinking: truly polymorphic DBs are still SF now. Anyway, my next question is in fact on Faunus...

Comment: I just wanted to test hbase integration with falcon for now. Do you know the properties I can set to replace berkeleyje with hbase?

Comment: The main reason for me to think about habse is for 'failover'. What if titan database gets corrupted, how do we recover the data? So, thinking of using hbase as it replicates the data.

Comment: A new link, because to old is broken:http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/data-model.html